# WhY in C programming ,perc value show 0 as output?

Tags: c

perc=(sum/total)*100;

i've been trying to put this in the code in cprogramming,but output for this part is showing 0,,,Why is this happening and what else should I do in these types of scenerios?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It should be obvious - the type and value of `sum` and `total` matter and we can't explain the result without knowing those.

Comment: you can infer sum < total, and that integer division is causing this to be 0, which then 0*100 assigns 0 to perc.

Comment: Welcome @Intishar, please provide minimal working code and elaborate your question properly, so that it is easy to understand and guide you accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didnt post source and this question will be closed soon, the cause is from integer division most likely.  Try this instead.

```
float perc = ((float)sum / (float)total) * 100.0;
```

Heres a post on integer division if you are interested in learning why this behavior is doing what it did:
[What is the behavior of integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division)

Comment: @IntisharRahman you can use (double) too if you want to hold larger data but 0-100 should be fine with float.  Accept this answer as a solution to your question if it solved your problem (hit the green checkmark)